# Calling a function when neither of two elements is being hovered?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My idea is to have two variables, insideLink that marks if I'm currently hovering over my menu and insideBox that checks if I'm hovering over Div container.

And if I leave I check if I'm also out of the other element, if I'm out of both I call the closeboth function that closes them both.

I tried doing it like this, but it doesn't work. Box closes right away after I move away from the menu link.

I suppose setTimeout would help but, but my attempts with that didn't work quite well. Any ideas?

```js
$(linkID).hover(function() {
    insideLink=1;
    console.log("Its over Link");
},function() {
    insideLink=0;
    if (insideBox==0) {
      console.log("Its outside both elements, closebox"); 
      closebox();
    }
});

$(open).hover(function() {
    insideBox=1;
    console.log("Its inside box");
},function() {
    insideBox=0;
    if (insideLink==0) {
      console.log("Its outside both elements, closebox");
      closebox();
    }
});
```

Comment: you should make a jsfiddle.com out of this - might encourage more activity

Comment: Is it possible to show the html?

Comment: Am I guessing right or is that for an `ul li` menu dropdown ?

Comment: Its a menu however the "drop down div" is not in the list for various reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the `mouseout` of the link gets triggered before the `mouseover` of the box, one way is to use `setTimeout()`:

```
insideLink=0;
setTimeout(function() {
    if (insideBox==0) {
        console.log("Its outside both elements, closebox"); 
        closebox();
    }
}, 100);
```

It suspends the box closing action for 100ms, which should be enough for the `mouseover` event to get fired that sets `insideBox` to 1. The same can be applied to the `.hover()` of the box.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you mean something like this:

```
    <div  id="outerDiv" onmouseover="checkMouse()">
        Outer DIV <br />
        <div id="innerDiv">Inner DIV 
            <br /> Inner DIV <br />
        </div>
        Outer DIV <br />
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        function checkMouse(){

            if(window.event.target.id == 'outerDiv'){
                console.log( 'indise outer div');
            }
            else{
                console.log( 'indise inner div');
            }
        }
    </script>
```